# Execute a "docker exec -it" command within in a ubuntu cron job

Tags: bash, docker, ubuntu, cron

For a daily database backup, I created the following cron job :

File : ***crontab -e***

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin


* * * * * /bin/bash /var/path/deploy/database/scripts/backup.sh
```

File : ***/var/path/deploy/database/scripts/backup.sh***

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

cp -r /var/path/deploy/database/scripts /var/bricoolpathpostgresql/data

chmod 755 -R /var/path/postgresql/data

docker exec -it database /var/lib/postgresql/data/scripts/pg_backup_rotated.sh
```

When I execute the script directly it works well and the backup is created successfully. But the script is being excuted from the cron job the command `docker exec -it database /var/lib/postgresql/data/scripts/pg_backup_rotated.sh` does not seem to work.

I have no error output in */var/log/syslog*

Comment: You probably need to get rid of the -i as this means interactive. Which a cronjob is not

Comment: Which user runs this cronjob?

Comment: Maybe also the -t which means terminal. I am not sure if it needs one and has one

Comment: removing the i solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Danny Ebbers mentioned in comment, the problem ws the -i argument in Docker command.